# Crontab does not execute python script

Tags: cron

I have a DSB18B20 temperature sensor and would like to log the readings in a csv file.

I have a script templog.py that stores the readings in a file. The file starts with `#!/usr/bin/python` That works.

When I run `/usr/bin/python /home/pi/mypath/templog.py` the script runs as well.

I then tried to add a crontab for that.

```
sudo chmod -x templog.py
```

I was in the correct path for that, therefore no absolute path given.

```
sudo crontab -e

* * * * * /home/pi/mypath/templog.py

/1 * * * * /home/pi/mypath/templog.py

*/1 * * * * /home/pi/mypath/templog.py

/1 * * * * /usr/bin/python /home/pi/mypath/templog.py

/1 * * * * sudo /usr/bin/python /home/pi/mypath/templog.py
```

Neither of this works.

Comment: Who is owner of `templog.py` ?

Comment: I guess I am? I created the file but inserted snippets of code I found around the web.

Comment: You may check ownership via `ls -l`

Comment: The owner is root instead of pi.

Comment: You may change ownership and try again. see http://askubuntu.com/questions/6723/change-folder-permissions-and-ownership

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the script is executable.

`chmod +x /home/pi/mypath/templog.py`

To run every minute the correct crontab entry will then be

`* * * * * /home/pi/mypath/templog.py`

If you use the root crontab make sure root has permission to write to your log file.

It would probably be best to use your ordinary crontab.

`crontab -e` rather than `sudo crontab -e`.

Comment: I did chmod +x and used 5 stars in crontab as I posted in my question. Is there a reason to use crontab without sudo? I also guess I figured out what the problem was, I'll try and answer the question later. I had a relative path in my script and I think if using crontab I need to use absolute paths. I don't know why that took me 3 hours to figure out though.